# Could not be able to bundle paperclip

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I bundled a gemfile, and all installed perfect except paperclip, I could not figure out what is the problem, anyone could help me? thanks in advance!

```
  Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-
  2.5.0/test/fixtures/question?mark.png
  An error occured while installing paperclip (2.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue
  .
  Make sure that `gem install paperclip -v '2.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that's caused by trying to [create a file with a question mark in the name](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/11a09fbf77e9e614ed6134c72b914cad3779d1e6), which isn't valid on Windows. It looks like `2.4.4` is the newest version that doesn't contain that commit, so try forcing your `Gemfile` to use that exact version.

File a bug [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues?state=open), and link to it in a comment. (I would if I had Windows and could test this).

Comment: I did not try other version, just restarted my OS and it works now, Thanks any way!

Answer (score 0):

You can install Paperclip 2.6.0 and rename manually in gems folder to 2.5.0. And don't forget to rename gem version to 2.5.0 in paperclip-2.5.0.gemspec file. It will work without any problem.